# User accepting Spotify permissions for authentication

Tags: flutter, oauth, spotify

I am new to Flutter and have been working on an app that allows users to login into their Spotify account. I actually am having trouble where after the user agrees to the permission screen, it should return back to the app with the callback containing the access token. But in my case, when I click agree, it returns a PlatformException saying the 'User cancelled login'. Not sure what is happening.

The error:
`I/flutter ( 3861): PlatformException(CANCELED, User canceled login, null, null)`

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(CANCELED, User canceled login, null, null)
E/flutter ( 6868): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
E/flutter ( 6868): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:315:18)
E/flutter ( 6868): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6868): #2      FlutterWebAuth.authenticate (package:flutter_web_auth/flutter_web_auth.dart:41:12)
E/flutter ( 6868): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6868): #3      Spotify.userAuthorization (package:soundrise/spotify/main.dart:47:20)
E/flutter ( 6868): <asynchronous suspension>
```

For context: I am using flutter_web_auth to open the Spotify auth screen.

```
try {
      final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
          url: url, callbackUrlScheme: 'soundrise.page.link');
      print(result);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

Comment: same issue here... Were you able to figure out?